# HackerEarth code of Monk and Rotation in java

Tags: java

Language Java 8

Input     Result           Time (sec)   Memory(KiB) Score

Input #1      Accepted  0.075553        85528             10

Input #2     Accepted   0.098481        86132             10

Input #3     Accepted   0.147306        84196             20

Input #4     Accepted   0.522715        91428            20

**Input #5  Time limit exceeded 2.0015  99836   0**

Input #6      Accepted  0.155435        84072           20

Time limit exceeded?

<kbd>Java Code</kbd>

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class TestClass {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = sc.nextInt();
        while(t > 0){
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int k = sc.nextInt();
        int a[] = new int[n];
        k = k % n;
        int count = k;
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            a[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < n ; i++){
            if(count > 0){
                System.out.print(a[n - k + i] + " ");
                count--;
            }
            else{
                System.out.print(a[i - k] + " ");
            }
        }
        t--;
        System.out.println("");
        }
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try writing to a *[StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)* class first, and then to *System#out*.

```java
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
int t = sc.nextInt(), n, k, a[], count, i;
while(t > 0){
    a = new int[n = sc.nextInt()];
    count = k = sc.nextInt() % n;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) a[i] = sc.nextInt();
    for(i = 0; i < n ; i++)
        if (count <= 0) s.append(a[i - k]).append(' ');
        else {
            s.append(a[n - k + i]).append(' ');
            count--;
        }
    t--;
    s.append('\n');
}
System.out.println(s);
sc.close();
```